# Pass complex objects through javascript to a .Net Service

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, soap, asmx

I'm trying to figure out how to send a complex object through javascript to my C# webservice.

Here xml string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=utf-8?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>
<SaveResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <RL>
    <response_entries>
      <ResponseEntry>
        <response_id>string</response_id>
        <account_id>string</account_id>
        <organization_id>string</organization_id>
        <form_header_id>string</form_header_id>
        <status>string</status>
        <field0>string</field0>
        <field1>string</field1>
        <field99>string</field99>
      </ResponseEntry>
      <ResponseEntry>
        <response_id>string</response_id>
        <account_id>string</account_id>
        <organization_id>string</organization_id>
        <form_header_id>string</form_header_id>
        <status>string</status>
        <field0>string</field0>
        <field1>string</field1>
        <field99>string</field99>
      </ResponseEntry>
    </response_entries>        
  </RL>
</SaveResponse>
```

Example of what I'm trying to send:

[image]

Comment: This is barely readably, why not just paste the text?

Comment: Do you control the server? I'd be writing this as a json service, not SOAP... and if I don't, I think I'd write a json service that acts as a proxy to the SOAP service ;p

Comment: @Marc Yes.  I have control over the server. I have not much experience with JSON. I did create a JSOn 
service one time. 
Ex. 
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public String  GetFormByFormHeaderIDJSON(String form_header_id)
{
 FormFunctions FF = new FormFunctions();
 return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(FF.GetFormByFormHeaderID(form_header_id));
}

Is this what you mean?  Still confused on calling the web service from the client side?  Have an example I can work with?

Comment: @Hitesh well, it doesn't even need to be a [MebMethod] - any handler that takes a json body and runs it through JavaScriptSerializer should work fine.

Comment: @Hitesh Rana, shame on you for including a bunch of code in a comment and not even putting it in a code block.

Comment: @Marc.  I never called a service or a handler from JavaScript.  Have an example in JavaScript that passes a complex over to a service or handler? Thanks btw, for the quick reply.

Comment: @Nick I did not know you can put in code blocks in comment. Sorry.

Comment: @Hitesh Rana, there is no button for it, you need to prepend and append it with the ` symbol. (button left of 1 key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Marc mentioned, it is very easy to use JSON in javascript, so lets do that:

First create a web service:

```
[WebMethod]
public string DoStuff(string json)
{
    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    MyType input = js.Deserialize<MyType>(json);
    return js.Serialize(DoStuff(input));
}
```

That input is a json string which JavaScriptSerializer will turn into a .NET object very easily.  DoStuff(MyType) is a method you define that takes whatever input you need and does stuff with it.

Now it's time to consume (I'm using GET here, but if it's active you should POST):

```
$.get("TestService.asmx/DoStuff", { json: jsonString })
    .success(function (data) { 
        // code goes here!
    });
```

use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to serialize the jsonString from a javascript object